# Mount & unmount volume notifications

Tags: macbook-pro

For the last month or so, I have been receiving notification windows in the upper right-hand corner whenever a volume is mounted or unmounted (i.e. portable hard drive, Time Machine, etc.) How do I turn these notifications off?

Comment: As far as I know, this isn't built in to the system. Do you remember installing any software to trigger this?

Also, do you just mean that an icon appears on the desktop, or a real notification box appears?

Answer (score 5):

If Growl is installed and you want to turn off just the notifications for volume mounts and dismounts (as opposed to getting rid of Growl altogether):

- System Preferences, Growl panel
- Applications tab
- Select HardwareGrowler from the list
- Configure
- Notifications tab
- In the dropdown, for each notification (e.g. Volume Mounted) you want to disable:
- Select it and untick the 'Enabled' box.

(Edit:) Or, as fnurl points out, remove HG entirely.
I find it useful enough to keep, but tweaked to my liking.  It alerts me if my WiFi starts bouncing, f/ex.  YMMV, as always.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if you have Growl installed - it will be in System Preferences. Sometimes applications install it without your permission - even though the growl team explicitly don't allow it. Its safe though, I use and love the product.

Answer (score 1):

I use HardwareGrowler to get these messages.

Perhaps HardwareGrowler is launching at startup? If you do not want this, go to

*System Preferences → Accounts → Your Account → Login items*

and find HardwareGrowler and remove it from the list.